# How does a Function determine the number of arguments

Tags: assembly, machine-code

Given a Function with 3 Parameters:

```
Foo(int a, int b, int c)
```

In assembly the Caller writes the 3 values into the registers rdi, rsi and rdx.
But how does the Function Foo know that rdx is the last register for his arguments?

Comment: While deliberate abuse is possible, normally the compiler makes sure that the function that expects three arguments receives exactly three.  Depends on language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been written to expect 3 arguments passed according to some calling convention. It doesn't know and can't check how many it actually got. It will happily use whatever happens to be in those registers, whether the caller filled in proper arguments or not. The caller and the callee should agree on the arguments and the calling convention.

Comment: Okay, thank you that was a real eye opener for me. Clearly the function can not access another (4th) argument.